# Need to know about uses-feature in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

`uses-feature` is used in following way:

```
  <uses-feature
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"]
  android:glEsVersion="integer" />
```

What is the use of `android:required` and `android:glEsVersion`?

Comment: RTFM... I typed "android:required" in google, found the answer in less than 10 seconds. You should have done the same. -1

Comment: I know about this there is some issue I am facing so need to know by using same can that thing be happen or there is some other issue..

Comment: The above makes no sense, but if you're having another problem, why is that not included in the question ? I wish I could -1 again... Here's something you should read : [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`required` is used to show that the feature the app uses is essential to the application; without that feature the app would be useless or wouldn't work. If your app uses gps, for example, as a *nice-to-have* feature but it isn't absolutely necessary, you could set `required` to `false`. This way, users with devices that don't have devices with gps can still download your app from the Play Store—which they otherwise couldn't.

`glEsVersion` is necessary only if the feature requires OpenGL ES. In that case you might want to specify at least one version to be used in the context.

---

Or as the developer guidelines state:

> **required** The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it. *([Android Dev Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html))*
>
> **glEsVersion** For some features, there may exist a specific attribute that allows you to define a version of the feature, such as the version of Open GL used (declared with glEsVersion). […] An application should specify at most one android:glEsVersion attribute in its manifest. If it specifies more than one, the android:glEsVersion with the numerically highest value is used and any other values are ignored. If an application does not specify an android:glEsVersion attribute, then it is assumed that the application requires only OpenGL ES 1.0, which is supported by all Android-powered devices. *([Android Dev Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html))*

You can read more about `<uses-feature>` in the [Android Developer Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: So, you mean if I use  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" /> like this is not essential to my app.

Comment: @amanarora Exactly. You would use that so devices without wifi (are there any out there?) could still download your app from the Play Store although they don't have wifi because you specified that the feature `wifi` is not required.

Comment: Ok Thanks, one more thing, by using this either it can block that feature? Forex: if android:required="true" should using this block wifi?

Comment: Does this mean if required is false there's no need for the line? If I want to filter out devices, I'd set required=true. If required=false, and I allow for all devices to list the app, is this line even required?

Answer (score 2):

android:required is useful when every device not support hardware or feature which your app needs.

Example : My app is useful for backup purpose of SMS,contact,calllog,apk etc. But some tablets doesn't has sim card then android:required="false" work for me if that app run on that device.

> android:glEsVersion The OpenGL ES version required by the application.
>   The higher 16 bits represent the major number and the lower 16 bits
>   represent the minor number. For example, to specify OpenGL ES version
>   2.0, you would set the value as "0x00020000", or to specify OpenGL ES 3.0, you would set the value as "0x00030000".

Answer (score 2):

As described in android [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html):

The `<uses-feature>` lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature.

The `android:glEsVersion` The OpenGL ES version required by the application.