# Playstore is not showing the app in some device

Tags: android

I can install app using apk i have generated and run through adb. But problem is my app is not shown in google playstore using the same device (android version 4.4.2).
These are permissions used in android manifest

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<permission
    android:name="com.tsering.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.tsering.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<permission
    android:name="com.tsering.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.tsering.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".Utils.tsering"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.singup">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoggedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_promotion"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PromoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_promo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="------" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".BarcodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_barcode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->
    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>

    <!-- SMS Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--
  Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
  dispatching on non-Google Play devices
-->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <!--
         Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
         installation campaign reporting
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
</application>
```

Comment: please post the rest of the manifiest pls.

Comment: which device u use and post the full manifiest.

Comment: If you have just published, please wait a few hours before it appears in the store.

Comment: still missing some manifiest lines...

Comment: My app has already been published and is working fine on most of the device. The problem is playstore is not showing on Samsung duos Galaxy star (4.4.2)

Comment: What is your min & target api version

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad 
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: & where is <supports-screens> in manifest ?

Comment: thats all i have....

Answer (score 0):

As I can not see the Screen Support in manifest, add this to your manifest

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

PlayStore didn't ask for any special thing for any specific devices, try adding the maximum support you can provide

Instead of this

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Use This

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: still not working your device isn't compatible with this version on playstore

Comment: uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true", now what came in my mind is any thing like this.. is there any thing which is required set true & your phone doesn't have that

Comment: Read the accepted Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674528/need-to-know-about-uses-feature-in-android

Comment: I hope I have given you the direction

Comment: no.. set true ensure that the feature for what you have set required true must be in the device for you App to run on that specific device.. If I give you a requirement that make an App that should only run on devices that have front camera, so you will set front camera required to true then App will only visible from play store to those devices that have front camera

Comment: no man.. But i know what is the problem... I have four app out of them 3 have map in it.. Those three app are not shown and 4th one is shown.. So the problem got to be Google map and glEsVersion should be true as suggested by others........